# Replace exact substring in python

Tags: python, regex, string

Example string: `"office administration in delhi"`

I want to replace in from the string with a blank. But when I do, `s.replace('in',"")`, the in of administration also becomes blank.

This is just a sample. The string and the word to replace may vary.

Is there some way to replace only the exact match?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use regular expression `\bin\b`. `\b` here means [word boundary](http://%3E%3E%3E%20import%20re%20%3E%3E%3E%20re.sub(r'%5Cbin%5Cb',%20'',%20'office%20administration%20in%20delhi')%20'office%20administration%20%20delhi'). `\bin\b` will match `in` surrounded by word boundary (space, punctuation, ...), not `in` in other words.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\bin\b', '', 'office administration in delhi')
'office administration  delhi'
```

See [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub).