# Is there a way to .replace() certain string snippets according to a criteria?

Tags: python, string, replace

I'm importing from a .txt file containing some David Foster Wallace that I copy-pasted from a PDF. Some words ran off the page and so come in the form of

```
"interr- upted"
```

I was going to sanitize it by using something like:

```
with open(text, "r", 0) as bookFile:
    bookString = bookFile.read().replace("- ", "")
```

Except... the man also uses some weird constructions in his writing. Things like:

```
"R - - d©"
```

for the brand name bug spray Raid©. I'm left with "R d©" obviously, but is there a way to make it .replace() instances of "- " but not instances of " - "? Or do I need to turn everything into lists and do operations to everything that way? Thanks.

Comment: How would you define this condition? Is it only if there are one or more letters, hyphen, space, one or more letters?

Comment: Good point. I want the case to be more general, so that when I do the same to future books any instance of "a - - b" won't get thrown away, but similar run-off words in the form of "ab- c" will get turned into "abc".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a regular expression with a negative lookbehind assertion to check the previous character, and [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) to replace matches with an empty string.

`'(?<! )- '` is a regular expression, matching all instances of `'- '`, *not* preceded by a single space character (refer to [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) section for the syntax). `re.sub('(?<! )- ', '', input_string)` will replace all occurrences of the `'(?<! )- '` pattern in `input_string` with `''` (empty string) and return the result.

Examples:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: re.sub('(?<! )- ', '', 'interr- upted')
Out[2]: 'interrupted'

In [3]: re.sub('(?<! )- ', '', 'R - - d©')
Out[3]: 'R - - d©'
```

Comment: This worked perfectly - my input was just the entire text file as one string, and it truncated every instance of "- " without destroying "R - - d©" or "f - - k" or any regular hyphenated words. Is there any chance you could explain what's going on in the re.sub() args you chose? The documentation is a little confusing, never used regular expressions before.

Comment: @LukeMcPuke I tried to explain it better, check the updated answer. For the complete explanation of that regular expression see the linked documentation and [this](https://regex101.com/r/5HNEha/1) page

Answer (score 2):

You can use lookbehinds and lookaheads to make sure you substitute only the occurrences that need to be substituted:

```
>>> import re
>>> regex_pattern = '(?<=[a-z])(- )(?=[a-z])'
>>> re.sub(regex_pattern, '', "interr- upted", re.I)
'interrupted'
```

And,

```
>>> re.sub(regex_pattern, '', "R - - d©")
'R - - d©'
```

The latter is not affected.

Answer (score -2):

is this what you need?

```
In [23]: import re
In [24]: re.sub(r'- ', '', '"R - - d"')
Out[24]: '"R d"'
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31697043/replace-exact-substring-in-python) link can help you.

HTH

Comment: No, OP very clearly mentioned this is not what they need.