# Replace every instance of a word with another word without breaking other words containing that word

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, replace

Word, word, word... Sorry for the title.

Let's say I want to replace every instance of "yes" to "no" in a string. I can just use string.replace(). But then there's this problem:

```
string = "yes eyes yesterday yes"
new_str = string.replace("yes", "no")

# new_str -> "no eno noterday no"
```

How can I preserve "eyes" and "yesterday" as is, with changing "yes" to "no".

Comment: put spaces around em.

Comment: @Paul Collingwood What about when it's in the beginning or the end...? It doesn't work. Edit: or followed by a dot or a comma

Comment: [Python regular expression match whole word](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15863066/1324033)

Comment: [Replace exact substring in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31697043/1324033)

Comment: it's a start right? :P for homework problems I only give hints.

Comment: It's not actually a homework problem... I'm not even learning code in school. Thanks for the effort tho ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace exact substring in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31697043/replace-exact-substring-in-python)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Search and replace with "whole word only" option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17730788/search-and-replace-with-whole-word-only-option)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
" ".join(["no" if word=="yes" else word for word in string.split()])
```

> ```
> 'no eyes yesterday no'
> ```

---

The explanation:

First, break the string into a list of individual words:

```
string.split()
```

> ```
> ['yes', 'eyes', 'yesterday', 'yes']
> ```

Then iterate over this list of individual words and use the expression

```
"no" if word=="yes" else word
```

to replace every `"yes"` with `"no"` in a list comprehension

```
["no" if word=="yes" else word for word in string.split()]
```

> ```
> ['no', 'eyes', 'yesterday', 'no']
> ```

Finally, return this changed list back to a string with the `.join()` method of the string `" "` (the delimiter).

Answer (score 5):

You can use `re` here.

```
re.sub(r'\byes\b','no',"yes eyes yesterday yes")
# 'no eyes yesterday no'
```

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

`\b`-
Matches the empty string, but only at the beginning or end of a word. A word is defined as a sequence of word characters. Note that formally, `\b` is defined as the boundary between a `\w` and a `\W` character (or vice versa), or between `\w` and the beginning/end of the string. This means that `r'\bfoo\b'` matches `'foo'`, `'foo.'`, `'(foo)'`, `'bar foo baz'` but not `'foobar' or 'foo3'`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
import re

string = "yes eyes yesterday yes"
new_str = re.sub(r"\byes\b", "no", string)
```

**Output:**

```
no eyes yesterday no
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use regex, you can specify word boundaries with `\b`:

```
import re

sentence = 'yes no yesyes'

sentence = re.sub(r'\byes\b', 'no', sentence)
print(sentence)
```

Output:

```
no no yesyes
```

Notice that 'yesyes' is not changed (to 'no').

You can read more about Python's `re` module [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).