# python use re.sub with a dict to replace multi exact substrings

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

In python, I am trying to use re.sub with a **dict** to replace multi "**exact**" substrings. The following is a sample example.

```
import re

words = "apple pineapple cat category data old_data"
dic = {"apple":"apple_new", "cat":"cat_new", "data":"data_new"}

pattern = re.compile("|".join(dic.keys()))

new_words = re.sub(pattern, lambda m: dic[m.group(0)], words)
```

The result is :

```
apple_new pineapple_new cat_new cat_newegory data_new old_data_new
```

The result I expected is :

```
apple_new pineapple cat_new category data_new old_data
```

What should I do?
I have tried [Replace exact substring in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31697043/replace-exact-substring-in-python) methods (r"\b...\b")

```
new_words2 = re.sub(r"\bapple\b", "apple_new", words)
```

It can reach my goals. But in my real project, I have to replace about 100 patterns at once. So I hope can use **dict** with r"\bapple\b"

If you know how to do, please tell me, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify `pattern` definition to:

```
pattern = re.compile(fr'\b(?:{"|".join(dic.keys())})\b')
# re.compile(r'\b(?:apple|cat|data)\b', re.UNICODE)
```

output of `re.sub(pattern, lambda m: dic[m.group(0)], words)`:

```
'apple_new pineapple cat_new category data_new old_data'
```

Answer (score 2):

We can try placing word boundaries around your regex alternation, to prevent accidental unwanted substring matches.  Also, strictly speaking we should also use `re.escape` on each entry in the alteration.

```py
import re

words = "apple pineapple cat category data old_data"
dic = {"apple":"apple_new", "cat":"cat_new", "data":"data_new"}

pattern = r'\b(' + r'|'.join([re.escape(x) for x in list(dic.keys())]) + r')\b'
new_words = re.sub(pattern, lambda m: dic[m.group(0)], words)
print(new_words)  # apple_new pineapple cat_new category data_new old_data
```