# python use re.sub with a dict to replace first substring in each line

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

In [python use re.sub with a dict to replace multi exact substrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73691886/python-use-re-sub-with-a-dict-to-replace-multi-exact-substrings)
I use re.sub with a dict to replace multi "exact" substrings.

```
import re

words = " apple pineapple cat category data old_data"
dic = {"apple":"apple_new", "cat":"cat_new", "data":"data_new"}

#pattern = re.compile("|".join(dic.keys()))
pattern = r'\b(' + r'|'.join([re.escape(x) for x in list(dic.keys())]) + r')\b'
new_words = re.sub(pattern, lambda m: dic[m.group(0)], words)

print(new_words)
```

**Now I want to just replace first substring in each line. Original words is :**

```
words = " apple cat data old_data\n     pineapple category data old_data\n   data old_data"
```

The result I expected is:

```
words = " apple_new cat data old_data\n     pineapple category data old_data\n   data_new old_data"
```

It keeps spaces and \n, just replace first substring in each line.
I have tried (\s*) to match 0~n spaces in each line, But it doesn't work.

```
pattern = r'\s*\b(' + r'|'.join([re.escape(x) for x in list(dic.keys())]) + r')\b'
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: The simplest fix by far is to add `count=1` to the `re.sub` invocation.

Answer (score 0):

Use `re.sub` with a callback function to replace on every line.  Then lookup each first word in your current dictionary.  If found, make the replacement and otherwise no-op.

```
import re

words = " apple cat data old_data\n     pineapple category data old_data\n   data old_data"
dic = {"apple":"apple_new", "cat":"cat_new", "data":"data_new"}

def repl(m):
    if m.group(1) and m.group(1) in dic:
        return dic[m.group(1)]
    else:
        return m.group(1)

output = re.sub(r'^\s*(\w+)', repl, words, flags=re.M)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
apple_new cat data old_data
pineapple category data old_data
data_new old_data
```

Comment: Thank you. This method has a problem. It deletes spaces before first substring in each line.  How can I do to keep spaces?

Comment: @胡峻誠 Remove the `^\s*` from the regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can start matching at the start of a line and grab any chars, as few as possible, before the matching `key`, and replace accordingly:

```py
pattern = r'(?m)^(.*?)\b({})\b'.format(r'|'.join([re.escape(x) for x in list(dic.keys())]))
new_words = re.sub(pattern, lambda m: f'{m.group(1)}{dic[m.group(2)]}', words)
```

Output:

```py
>>> print(new_words)
 apple_new cat data old_data
     pineapple category data_new old_data
   data_new old_data
```

The `(?m)^(.*?)` means: match the start of a line (`(?m)^`) and then capture into Group 1 any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible.

The `f'{m.group(1)}{dic[m.group(2)]}'` replacement is a concatenation of Group 1 and the value of the found key.

Note that `\b` word boundaries won't work in case your keys start or end with special chars. In that case, use [the adaptive dynamic word boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45145800/3832970).

If you have thousands of keys, use a [regex trie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68154589/3832970) rather than `'|'.join(...)`.